# binding issue with sap.m.List and model configured in manifest.json

Tags: json, sapui5

i need to show the list with items are binding to the model which is configured in the manifest.json for component.

model which configured in manifest.json

```
"models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "com.xxxxx.yy.DemandFilter.i18n.i18n"
                }
            },
            "priority": {
                    "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
                    "uri": "model/priority.json"
            },
            "status": {
                    "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
                    "uri": "model/status.json"
            }  
        }
```

the priority and status json are just array of objects as below

```
{
"status":[
 {
 "name" : "Created",
 "selected":false
 },
{
 "name" : "Processed",
 "selected":false
 },
 {
 "name" : "Released",
 "selected":false
 },
 {
 "name" : "Completed",
 "selected":false
 },
 {
 "name" : "Closed",
 "selected":false
 }]
}
```

i am placing the view through Component as below

```
new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                height : "100%",
                name : "com.xxxxx.yyy.DemandFilter"
            })
```

My view is XML view and list is added as below

```
<List headerText="{i18n>status}" items="{ path:'status>/status' }"
                selectionChange="onStatusSelection" mode="MultiSelect">
                <items>
                    <InputListItem label="{name}" selected="{selected}">
                    </InputListItem>
                </items>
            </List>
```

The Number of list items are correct but the name and selected are not binding properly

[image]

if i set the model to the view in onInit of the Controller this is working fine.

Please suggest me where i have made the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties of control also need to be specified with model's alias.

```
<InputListItem label="{status>name}" selected="{status>selected}">
```